# Split delimited (, ; #) string using SPD 2013

Tags: workflow, string

Need support in splitting a text (Single line text field/Multi line text field- Plain Text) which has delimiters and create new items in other library/list.

Tried using sample SPD 2013 workflow, but unable to achieve exact result. (W/f [image] [image]running into infinite loop)

Below are the screen shots.

Eg: List A
Text Field -- Name: Suresh,Rajesh,Kumar 
ID: 3

List/Library B

ID  Name1      Name2        Name3 
3   Suresh     Rajesh        Kumar

Sudhir

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are not replacing the comma after replacing the substring. The WF keeps on finding the comma at 0th position and loop becomes infinite.

Modify your loop as shown below (tried and tested).

[image]

When you replace `substring1` it should be `[substring1],`

Comment: Hi, thank you.  done with changes and tried, the output at list3/ (lookup3 is running infinite loop when replaced with " _ " and with " , " splits only first word if we have 3 countries/words). Can you suggest where am i going wrong..

Comment: Don't replace with underscore. Replace with a space - " ". Can you post new screenshots after replacing with space?

Comment: Hi Harshal,replaced with " " but the output is looping infinite.Attached all the screen shots. kindly help

Comment: 3rd last line where you replace - it should be replace "[substring1]," . Do not forget that "comma" is to be removed along with substring1. This was the only reason your wf was going into infinity loop. I have mentioned that.

Comment: Thank you Harshal, Solved and got desired results

Comment: Please delete your answer and upvote and mark this as answer - https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers